# how to suppress background in the image using technique other than color based approach?

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: click here for image]
[image: click here for image]
I have an image of some whole wheat/triticale grains upon the powdered grains. I need to segment these grains. As, background color is same as grain color, I cannot use color segmentation.
My question is how can i suppress background retaining only grain?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO! Could you provide us a code snippet of what you've tried so far to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilites i can think of:

1. Semantic segmentation e.g. with UNET
2. Have you tried basic edge detectors